# Carbon emacs problem

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs, carbon-emacs

I installed Carbon EMACS tody but I have a problem with the shift key: I can't select region hoding down shift and moving with harrows. Do you have any suggestion?

Best
Riccardo

Comment: Why are you using carbon emacs when emacs23 has a native cocoa build that you can download @ http://emacsformacosx.com/

Comment: +1 Switch to Cocoa Emacs.app.

Answer (score 1):

I cecked C-h v but minibuffer do not match shift select mode; I also check C-h k both with shift and nothing appens, and shift+arrow and emacs explain to me only the arrows function.

I also tyed to create a new .emacs file only with :

(setq shift-select-mode t)

Nothing has changed, I still have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
(cua-selection-mode t)
```

Look [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/CuaMode) for more details. This should work on Emacs versions <23.

Answer (score 0):

Check <kbd>C-h v</kbd> `shift-select-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

If that's okay, then check the <kbd>C-h k</kbd> `(shift + arrow)` keys to see whether they are bound to something other than the forward/backward char and next/previous line movement commands.

Comment: I cecked C-h v but minibuffer do not match shift select mode; I also check C-h k both with shift and nothing appens, and shift+arrow and emacs explain to me only the arrows function.

I also tyed to create a new .emacs file only with :

(setq shift-select-mode t)

Nothing has changed, I still have the same problem

Comment: If emacs doesn't recognise `shift-select-mode` as a variable, then that would explain why this doesn't work for you. The feature was introduced in GNU Emacs 23.1. You can use `M-x version` to find out which version of Emacs you are running. It sounds like you might want to follow Steve Lianoglou's suggestion above to get a more up-to-date Emacs.

Comment: The version is the GNU Emacs 22.3.1 (i386-apple-darwin9.8.0, Carbon Version 1.6.0) of 2010-01-10 on gs674-seijiz.local. 
And sò I can't use shift to select region.... Is there a way to resolve the problem??

Comment: Karthik's answer sounds like it will help with your current version. I'd still recommend you upgrade if you're able. As Steve pointed out, emacsformacosx.com provides a current build of standard GNU Emacs.